# SPA (Single Page Application) with multiple html files

Tags: html, kendo-ui, single-page-application, icenium

It's my first time dealing with SPA, I am starting a cross platform mobile application using Kendo UI, I am using Icenium as my development tool, since I have a large group of views in my application I started putting the contents of the views in different html pages, so I have several html files with the current content only:

```
<div data-role="view" id="demoView"  data-layout="layout">     
        /* this is put in single file (demoView.html) */     
</div>
```

So now when I want to navigate to that view I would use something like

```
href="views/demoView.html"
```

instead of

```
href="#demoView.html"
```

So I am wondering if it is still a SPA even with the multiple html pages, as in does all the pages load at run-time? And is there any way to check the loaded html. files after the app is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Kendo UI Mobile, then yes, it will still act like a SPA with the built-in routing capabilities of Kendo UI Mobile. The remote views (on your other HTML docs) are still dynamically injected into your base DOM. The other pages/views load on-demand, not when the app is first initialized.